# Mysql convert table from long format to wide format

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, database-table

I have a MySQL table like this:

[image]

And I want to convert it from long format to wide format like this

[image]

Sorry. I'm new and don't know how to post a table

Comment: you should use the pivot table to get it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into goodTable 
select
bt.id,
(select bt1.value from badTable bt1 where bt1.info = 'firstname' and bt1.id = bt.id),
(select bt1.value from badTable bt1 where bt1.info = 'lastname' and bt1.id = bt.id),
(select bt1.value from badTable bt1 where bt1.info = 'phone' and bt1.id = bt.id)
from
 badTable bt
group by id ;
```

Working fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45f29e/2

Comment: Great answer, i use your commands and it works fine, thanks you very much

Comment: How does this optimize compared to a pure `group by` solution with no subqueries?

Comment: How about if city and address gets added to info? Then those also should be converted to new columns like firstname and lastname. 
Is there a way to dynamically handle this instead of hardcoding in inner query?

Answer (score 8):

You need something like this:

```
select id,
       max(case when info='firstname' then value else null end), 
       max(case when info='lastname' then value else null end), 
       ...
   from table
   group by id;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
SELECT  P.`info`,
        (CASE 
            WHEN P.`action`='fname' AND P.`id` = '1'OR'2' 
            THEN P.`id` 
            ELSE NULL 
        END)AS 'firstname',

        (CASE 
            WHEN P.`action`='lname' AND P.`id` = '2' OR'2'
            THEN P.`id` 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS 'lastname',

        (CASE 
            WHEN P.`action`='phone' AND P.`id` = '1'OR'2' 
            THEN P.`id` 
            ELSE NULL 
        END) AS 'phone'
FROM    tablename P
GROUP BY P.`info`;
```

Comment: The inclusion of the conditions on `ID` in your case statements makes no sense.